Is there a easier way to factorise a quartic polynomial (coefficient of $x^3=0$) into quadratic factors?
Is there a easier way to factorise a quartic polynomial into quadratic factors?
Take for example $f(x)=x^4+4x^2-x+6=0$
If I let $f(x)$= $(x^2-ax+b)(x^2+ax+6/b)$, and then compare coefficients, I get $ab-6a/b= -1$, and $b+6/b-a^2=4$, if I try to solve these , I again get a quartic equation in $b$ or $a$.
So , is the easiest method, or there is any other approach?

No, you don't get a quartic equation in $a$ or $b$, since you can first assume here that we solve the equations over the integers. Then, for example, $b$ can only be $\pm 1,\pm2,\pm 3,\pm 6$. This gives easy conditions on $a$.

FYI, a quartic without a cubic term is sometimes known as a "depressed quartic".

Your polynomial has the form $x^4+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$; in your case, $a_2=4$, $a_1=-1$, and $a_0=6$. Let $R(x)$ be the resolvent cubic of your polynomial, that is,\begin{align}R(x)&=x^3+2a_2x^2+\left(a_2^{\,2}-4a_0\right)x-a_1^{\,2}\\&=x^3+8x^2-8x-1.\end{align}Your problem becomes particularly easy to solve if $R(x)$ has a root of the form $\alpha^2$, for some $\alpha\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. In this case, that's what happens; you can just take $\alpha=1$. Then, if you take$$\beta=\frac12\left(a_2+\alpha^2-\frac{a_1}\alpha\right)=3\quad\text{and}\quad\gamma=\frac12\left(a_2+\alpha^2+\frac{a_1}\alpha\right)=2,$$you have\begin{align}x^4+4x^2-x+6&=(x^2+\alpha x+\beta)(x^2-\alpha x+\gamma)\\&=(x^2+x+3)(x^2-x+2).\end{align}

You method works perfectly, and you don't need to solve the quartic equation of $a$. Here is the details of the solution.
Define $f(x) = (x^2 -ax+b)(x^2 +ax+c)$ then
$$f(x) = x^4+\underbrace{(-a^2 +b+c)}_{=4}x^2 +\underbrace{a(b-c)}_{=-1}x+\underbrace{bc}_{=6}$$
It's evident that $a \ne 0$, then solve the two last equations $\cases{b-c = -\frac{1}{a}\\bc = 6}$ (which is equivalent to solve a quadratic equation and can be solved easily) for $(b,c)$ in function of $a$, we obtain
$$(b,c) = \left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+24a^2}}{2a} ,\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+24a^2}}{2a} \right) \tag{1}$$
$$\implies b+c = \pm \frac{\sqrt{1+24a^2}}{a} \tag{2}$$
Replace $(2)$ to the first equation:
$$\begin{align}
&\iff -a^2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{1+24a^2}}{a} = 4\\
&\iff \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+24a^2}}{a} \right)^2 = (4+a^2)\\
&\iff (1+24a^2) = a^2 (a^2 +4)^2\\
&\iff a^6 +8a^4-8a^2-1=0 \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
The equation $(3)$ is a cubic equation of $a^2$, and the good news is that it can be easily solved by factorization as follows
$$\begin{align}
(2)&\iff  (a^6 - 1) + 8a^2(a^2 -1) = 0\\
&\iff (a^2 -1)((a^4 + a^2 +1) + 8 a^2) =0\\
&\iff a^2 =1\\
&\iff a= \pm 1  \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
From $(4)$ and $(1)$, we deduce then
$$\color{red}{f(x) = (x^2-x +2)(x^2 + x+ 3)}$$
